# Passing a string from server side classic asp and client side javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, ms-access-2007

We are trying to create a web page. We are using MS-Access database and it is accessed using Classic ASP code.

The ASP code is retrieving the database information as a string.
We are using JavaScript for the client side programming. We want to pass the string obtained from the database(using ASP code) to the client side JavaScript.

How do we go about???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the string a name in your asp code eg

```
Dim mystring
mystring = RS("fieldname")
```

Then you can place `<%=mystring%>` within your JS wherever you want to use it.

The key thing to understand is that ASP code is rendered on the server before the page loads while JS is rendered by the browser after the page loads, so `<%=mystring%>` will appear as the string in your source code.

Comment: Does it work when .asp and .js are in different files and are called in the same html code?

Comment: The javascript would need to be in a .asp file if there was anything for the server to render. The .asp extension tells the server to process anything inside  `<%...%>`.  If you could provide a code sample I might be able to offer more suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from solution provide by John , there is one another way to achieve what you are trying to do:

you can save your database values in hidden fields or any other control and then in JavaScript you can find the value of controls as below.

**In ASP :**

```
<input type="hidden" id='hidname' value="<%=mystring%>" />
```

**In JavaScript:**

```
var v_name = document.getElementById("hidname").value;
```

Comment: What's the benefit of that over `var v_name = "<%=mystring%>";`? Also the OP doesn't ask for JQuery.

Comment: Just so people know:
<%=var%> is the SAME as <% Response.Write var %> it is just short hand.